# TypeORM findOne with nested relations

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I am having some issues performing a nested find query with TypeORM. Here's the basic code:

```js
    const { completionId } = req?.params;
    const user = req.user;

    const retrievedCompletion = await getRepository(
      CompletionGoogleSearch
    ).findOne({
      relations: ['run', 'run.user'],
      where: {
        id: completionId,
        // run: { user: { id: user.id } }, // This is the code that breaks the function
      },
    });

    console.log(retrievedCompletion?.run.user.id);
    console.log(user.id);
```

It looks to me like there's nothing out of order, and that the query should run. Any idea on what I am doing wrong? I know I can get around this issue by writing a querybuilder query or using raw SQL–I am just curious to understand if there's a flaw in my code.

Comment: The lastest typeorm version now support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're asking about doesn't supported on typeorm yet (Feb 2021).

Checkout this [issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707) that was opened on 2018.

Answer (score 20):

typeorm added the ability to use nested object

```
userRepository.find({
  relations: {
    profile: true,
    photos: true,
    videos: {
      videoAttributes: true,
    },
  },
});
```

on this way, you can fetch the data without using eager.

You can find more information [here](https://typeorm.io/find-options)

Comment: your answer is correct. I tried with my application and it worked with no issues.

Answer (score 6):

the Solution is use `eager:true` in `run.user` entity :

```
  @OneToOne(() => User, User=> User.run, {
    eager:true
  })
  user: User;
```

and next time you search in `CompletionGoogleSearch` do just `relations: ['run']` and user will come with it.

Comment: Your answer is also correct. I tried with my application and it worked with no issues. If I want to go with less json fields then I will choose @Yoav St his approach.